# Требуется ли запятая перед "как"?

Tags: как

И раз мир отнёсся к нему как к ничтожеству, почему бы ему не ответить тем же?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В этом предложении, скорее всего, запятая не ставится, поскольку сравнительный оборот тесно связан со сказуемым, и если его (оборот) убрать, то останется "мир отнёсся к нему", что будет незаконченным, непонятным выражением, то есть теряется смысл.

Answer (score 2):

*И раз мир отнёсся к нему как **к ничтОжеству**, почему бы ему не ответить **тЕм же?***

В этом предложении оборот действительно тесно примыкает к сказуемому *отнесся* и не обособляется, как и в большинстве случаев для этого глагола.

ОТНЕСТИСЬ, св. 1. к кому-чему. Составить своё представление о ком-, чём-л.; повести себя, встретить, принять что-л. каким-л. образом. О. к подросткам с пониманием.  Доброжелательно о. к заявлению депутата.

Тем не менее **исключения существуют**, поэтому тесную связь желательно проверить. При ее отсутствии ударение падает не только на оборот, но и на глагол или зависимое от него слово.

Примеры с обособлением:

*В Европе, благодаря использованию новых, более эффективных лекарств, **к спИду** стали относиться, **как к хроническому недУгу.***

*Только к **однОй** категории людей нужно относиться, **как к стоящим вЫше**. Тем, которых ты искренне уважаешь и желаешь чему-то научиться у них.*

*Но если вы станете обращаться с другими по-королевски вежливо, то, возможно, и к **вАм** станут относиться, **как к коронованной осОбе…***

*Но если **к БОгу** относиться, **как к родному,** если знать, что Бог озабочен о нас, что Он сострадает нам, что Он нас любит,  почему к Нему не обратиться...*